# git.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea, cygwin

I am working on project using git as a VCS. Development env is on winddows and project contains some long paths so I am forced to use `cygwin` with git.

I have installed cygwin with git, created ssh key, uploaded key to server and that all works fine from console.

But when I try to fetch, push, pull from `IntelliJ` I am receiving following error:

```
D:/cygwin/usr/libexec/git-core/git.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

I have installed `gettext` and `Devel\gettext` , `libsasl2` and `ca-certificates` packages for cygwin according to some recomendation I have found but this didn't solve the problem.

Here is my [IntelliJ git configuration](https://i.imgur.com/LmIswTL.png)

What I have to do to be able use git from cygwin within IntelliJ?

Comment: Make sure you have access rights and your keys set. It will give this error if you don't.

Answer (score 13):

I had the exact same problem. Also tried the gettext & sasl hints; didn't work.

The solution was very simple in the end: add your cygwin bin directory to the PATH.

(This surfaced when setting bash as Terminal in IntelliJ - it wouldn't even start grep.)

Comment: After reinstallin all somehow problem dissapears ... I do not know how.

Comment: Appending the `/cygwin/bin` directory to the PATH solved the problem for me.

Comment: where to add it ? @ThomasEizinger  in Environment variable ?? or Settings in IntelliJ ? i am getting the same problem ... but my path in IntelliJ looks fine ..

Comment: Yes, PATH is meant as the PATH environment variable. Appearantly, the cygwin console automatically adds the /cygwin/bin folder to PATH. For it to work from IntelliJ, you need to append it to the windows PATH env variable though.

Answer (score 6):

Add both `C:\cygwin\bin` AND `c:\cygwin` to the PATH.

Then restart IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 2):

For windows users, you can do this by adding the cygwin path to Environmental Variables, as show in the screenshot below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Just make sure, when you add cygwin to your path, you add it on 'Edit environment variables for your account' as shown below and under 'User variables' rather than under 'Edite system environment variables' - this won't work otherwise.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: System environment variables will work, you just need to reboot for it to take effect.