# tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address in Windows Pycharm debugger

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, pycharm

I am getting a red message every time I use the console from the debugger and try to see the output of a pandas object

```
"tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address"
```

I am using PyCharm 2016.3.2 and according to me I didn't update anything - it just started to appear all of a sudden. I attach a screenshot of the debugger with info on my ipython and debugger versions. Would appreciate your help to understand how to get rid of this message. It seems to appear both in the Python Console and Debugger Console, but not in the PyCharm Terminal. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround inside PyCharm itself without affecting the rest of the system:

You can hard code PATH as part of Environment set up under [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtjxK.png):

1. Click menu Run -> Edit/Configurations...
2. when the configuration window opens, click on Defaults -> Python.
3. On the right side under Environment Variables hard code PATH without git/cygwin. See below how to get that path from cmd prompt

   > import os, re; print ';'.join([p for p in os.getenv('PATH').split(';')
   >       if not re.search('Git', p)])
4. This PATH variable seems to overwrite system's path variable. 

   [Image of these steps overlaid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtjxK.png) in PyCharm.

[image: PyCharm Default Debug Configuration]

Comment: thanks @jedi, however the problem with this is that the change only applies to new python scripts created after that point. For all the previous scripts, which weren't created with those defaults, the same problem persists. Did you notice this as well for you?

Comment: Yes. Those are already stored in the PyCharm's configuration file. You can change them manually via  UI or edit the configuration file: .idea\workdspace.xml. If you have many of them you might want to ask system admin to update your path or write a script to add PATH to those configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jedi, really helpful

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to simply move `tput` to a different *cygwin* `PATH` directory,

e.g. if `tput` is in `~/git-for-windows/usr/bin`, and the same directory is in the **windows** PATH, moving tput.exe to `~/git-for-windows/usr/local/bin` will fix the issue in pycharm and still work within cygwin

Comment: thanks a lot for this nice fix! it worked for me by running this command `mv /usr/bin/tput.exe /usr/local/bin/.`. However, for `git push` to work in pycharm correctly, I had to ensure the git remote addresses were https and not ssh. You can check this with `git remote -v`. Btw, the git error I was getting before when fixing this tput error is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087523/git-exe-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed git or cygwin recently? If so, try to delete git or cygwin related paths from system environment variable PATH. If had the same problem as you and now have fixed it by doing so.

Comment: thanks! indeed, i recently reinstalled cygwin. Can you share how you deleted cygwin from the PATH though? I can't do this from System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> PATH -> Edit in Windows 7...

Comment: Many thanks! It is definitely because of having cygwin in my environment variable PATH. However, I don't seem to be able to delete it using the instructions you sent as in there PATH doesn't contain cygwin but somehow it gets appended at the end anyway as if I type PATH in cmd.exe, I can see it appended at the end. Somehow there seems to be another process doing this which I can't see. The way I fixed this was by manually removing it from the path in the Debugger console as this:

`import os` and then 
`os.environ['PATH'] = myNewPathWithoutCygwin`

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve the problem of not being able to delete Cygwin from the path as per the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978373/unable-to-remove-cygwin-from-path-environment-variable
Basically the user PATH is different from the system PATH but both get appended in the final PATH variable, so I was only looking at the system PATH

Comment: cygwin in PATH is definitely a culprit. The weird thing is that I had it there for ages, and the message start appearing just recently. Normally, I would've ignore that, but the console also started to hang on every second evaluation. Both issues have been resolved by removing cygwin's bin folder from system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer from H.J. Liu, if you are unable to delete cygwin from the system PATH, then it is probably in the user PATH. Please see this related post [Unable to remove cygwin from PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978373/unable-to-remove-cygwin-from-path-environment-variable/42986294#42986294)

Answer (score 0):

additional for Anaconda2 Users, you will find `tput.exe` in following two path:

`Anaconda2\Library\usr\bin
Anaconda2\pkgs\git-xxx\Library\usr\bin`

mv them to `xxx\usr\local\bin`

Answer (score 0):

My colleague had the same error. It occurred only for pandas.

We resolved it by changing the project interpreter in PyCharm to the anaconda one,  where he previously set up everything else. If for example, you use Anaconda navigator, then all the tput paths are set up there. (Maybe the settings got lost when downloading a new PyCharm version.)

I'm sharing this to give people some more ideas where to look for, not to get too focussed on cygwin.