# tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

Tags: tput

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address in Enthought Canopy. I am trying

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import numpy as np

data = [dict(
        visible = False,
        line=dict(color='00CED1', width=6),
        name = ' = '+str(step),
        x = np.arange(0,10,0.01),
        y = np.sin(step*np.arange(0,10,0.01))) for step in np.arange(0,5,0.1)]
data[10]['visible'] = True

steps = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    step = dict(
        method = 'restyle',
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(data)],
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active = 10,
    currentvalue = {"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad = {"t": 50},
    steps = steps
)]

layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, filename='Sine Wave Slider')
```

So getting error:

```
tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address
```

How can I correct this tput issue?

Comment: The plot is not coming, No such device or address notification is coming in output.

Comment: Do you use PyCharm? [This is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836245/tput-terminal-attributes-no-such-device-or-address-in-windows-pycharm-debugger).