# Cannot run C codes on vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have installed VScode and gitbash this afternoon on my Windows to pull and push C scripts for a project.

Everything is working fine but i can't run my scripts on the GitBash shell (error is : `..../main.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`)

neither on the PowerShell (compiling but returning nothing when I try to execute the exe file).

If i open a CMD window it's working fine.

I installed the 'code runner' extension to execute the code in one click, but i always get this error :

```
[Done] exited with code=3221225781 in 0.43 seconds
```

I already tried to execute the command line that the extension uses :

```
cd "c:\Users\....\" && gcc main.c -o main && "c:\....\"main
```

on an external cmd window and it's working fine

I also have MinGW in PATH.

Thank you

Comment: C isn't a scripting language, it's a compiled language. There's no such thing as a "C script".

Comment: My C "code" then

Comment: This is odd. It looks like a Linux error instead of a Windows one. If it works in CMD then I might just suggest to run it there.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087523/git-exe-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file Try adding Cygwin/MinGW directories to your PATH var.

Comment: I don't have cygwin, is it necessary to run codes on windows ?

Comment: No, absolutely not. If you don't have Cygwin then you can just add the Git Bash directories to your PATH.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by downloading "msvcr71.dll" and putting it into C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and C:\Windows\System32

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Installing random DLLs you find on the internet could give you a virus (especially in system32 and sysWoW64). If you got it from Microsoft, it might be OK, but it's probably better to install it with Windows Update.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Windows Update doesn't have a "give me this specific arbitrary DLL" feature.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica This is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime (or something like that), which should be present in windows update.

Comment: @S.S.Anne are you mixing up Windows Update with downloads from microsoft.com?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't think so. I remember having to constantly install the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime with Windows Update. If it's a download from microsoft.com, it's OK, but downloading it from some shifty website is not.

Comment: @S.S.Anne If you already have a Visual C++ runtime, Windows Update will offer you updates to it, but if you don't, it won't show you anything related to it.

Comment: OK, but the point is to not download DLL files from websites that you don't trust. You never know what malware could be in them, and putting them in such places as system32 and sysWoW64 is an incredibly bad idea.